# bibliography: Using a Numeric Citation Style

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing my thesis using Latex but I have one problem when cite websites.

In .bib file, the website is formatted using @misc:

```
 @misc{google,
     key = {Google Inc.},
     howpublished = {},
     note = {[online] link}},
     url = {http://www.google.com}
 }
```

In the main body, it is like as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

The search engine Google \cite{google}, ...
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

But it appears in main body like

```
The search engine Google [Google Inc.], ...
```

What I want is

```
The search engine Google [1], ...
```

And in the bibliography it appears like

```
[Google Inc.] Google Inc. [online] link.
```

What I want is

```
[1] Google Inc. [online] http://www.google.com.
```

Can anyone help me figure it out? Many thanks.

Comment: You need to show us the full minimal code so that we can reproduce the problem without the need of guessing.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thanks for reminding, I have modified my post so that you can try the code, please give me any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Do you use biblatex or bibtex?

Comment: Do you *cite* google? I would simply use a clickable link and/or add a footnote with the full url.

Comment: I use biblex @Dr.ManuelKuehner

Comment: Actually the code in the post is just an example. The problem is that I have to refer to many websites of different sensors in a table, it will exceed the range of the table cells if the citations appears as keys instead of numbers. @Johannes_B

Comment: Still, how about footnotes or notes (`threeparttable`)?

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for your advice, I will try footnotes later.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, It works as only change the bibliography style, it seems no need to use     filecontents. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong citation style and I don't know why you use the `key` key. In your example `google` is the key (which you use to refer to the item).

> I use the `filecontents` environment to generate the `bib` file. This will 
>   generate a file called `references.bib` with a single entry.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{url} % or hyperref

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
 @misc{google,
     author = {Google Inc.},
     howpublished = {},
     note = {[online]  \url{http://www.google.com}},
     url = {http://www.google.com}
 }
\end{filecontents}

% --------------------------------------------
% --------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\section*{Text}

The search engine Google \cite{google}, ...

% http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~surajit/present/bib.htm
% https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX-W%C3%B6rterbuch:_bibliographystyle
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

[image]

See [Wikibook](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX-W%C3%B6rterbuch:_bibliographystyle) (in German) or [this](http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~surajit/present/bib.htm) for the different standard `\bibliographystyle`s.

I compiled it using a batch file with this content:

```
pdflatex test
bibtex test
pdflatex test
pdflatex test
```

Where `test.tex` is the name of my LaTeX file.

> But in general I think that the `biblatex` package in combinantion with
>   `biber` is the way to go if you start a new project.

Comment: Please comment package `filecontents`. The risk is to high that a users just copy/paste/compile and loose their references.

Comment: On a different note: Are you really referencing the german wikibook these days? [How can we, as a community, improve the LaTeX WikiBook?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6393)

Comment: Hi @Dr.ManuelKuehner, I have followed your instructions and the citations of the websites can appear as numbers. But the other references (articles and conferences) are lost... It seems that the filecontents part rewrites the bib file. Thank god I saved my bib file... Can you tell me how to keep all the  other citations? And how to do it with biblatex and biber? Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Johannes_B, you saved me. I backed up my files before using file content package based on your advice.